# Magento 1.9 and 1.7 - "couldn't connect to host" when Installing extension and its not the version

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, e-commerce

First I would like to explain that I am only new to Magento.
I have recently placed magento in my hosting account in Awardspace.com and now I am trying to Install extensions from Magento connect and it shows **"couldn't connect to host"**.
1 - I tried looking on to the forums and everybody elses was resolved by the extension link version but didn't work for me.

2 - I also tried many different extensions but none worked.

 3 -I havent actually figured out how to download the extension and upload from the PC

Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want download magento extension in your pc got o this link.

http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

and paste you magento extension key in textarea then download zip file then you need paste in your magento, extension wil be work in your store if in admin 404 error shown on your extension setting logout and re login in admin panel it will be work.

if you install via Magento connect first give permission downloader folder on magento root.....it will be work...

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: Thank you Ravi, at least now I know how to download and install it, I done one there and it worked now I just need to see if any one knows how to get the Installation through the URL working.

Comment: Thanks for your comment can you please vote for my this post...if you like ....and if you want work with me mail to me rchomal09@gmail.com my mail id.